# background image in jumbotron in bootstrap isn't working

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-code, background-image

Tried everything I can think of, every solution suggested elsewhere online. This is the html code with the jumbotron div class. I am working in Python on Visual Studio Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <title>Bootstrap Cheatsheet</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/custom-style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
      <div class="bg-primary">
        <body>

            <div class="jumbotron">


            <div class="container">

              <h1 class="page-header">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>

                WOW! <small>.com</small></h1>

              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
                velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
                sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>   

          <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
          <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
              Enter a valid email address
            </div>


        </body>
      </div>  
  </html>
```

here is the corresponding CSS file with the 'milky way' image:

```
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url('../milky-way.jpg');
}

html {
    background-image: url('milky-way.jpg');
  }
```

The jumbotron comes up in the webpage but no image is displayed. I've tried moving the image to different folders etc and changing the URL but no success. I am a newbie and help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Does the background change to black? If so that means the css is being applied. Now try going back to your background image with the !important flag at the end. If it doesn't work, maybe it's an issue with your path?

Comment: I've fixed it. I was reloading a cached version of the page so it wasn't updating the changes. Thanks though